# Problema al conectame con localhost Unhandled Rejection (Error): [object ProgressEvent]

Tags: javascript, java

Estoy tratando de conectarme con localhost:8080 usando fetch, tengo un file cliente.js que conecta con el localhost para que me mustre en la consola un array de estudiantes el error que me muestra es Uncaught (in promise)

Quiero conectarme al localhost para que me regrese ese array de estudiantes y me los muestre en la consola para seber que si se conecto

```
import fetch from "unfetch";

export const getAllstudents = () => fetch('http://localhost:8080');
```

Quiero mostrar el resultado en la consola usando otro file llamado App.js
tiene este codigo

```
import "./App.css";
import { getAllstudents } from "./cliente";
import { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    getAllstudents().then(res =>
      res.json().then(students => {
        console.log(students);
      })
    );

    return <h1>hello world</h1>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

EL codigo java del servidor tiene un datos del studiante que quiero que me muestra la consola

```
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.demo.fristProyect.student.student.gender;


import java.util.List;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("students")
public class StudentController {
    
@GetMapping
    public List <student> getAllStudents()  {
        
        return java.util.List.of(
            new student("James", "Bond", "jamesbond@gmail.com", gender.MALE, UUID.randomUUID()),
            new student("Valeria", "Bond", "valeriabond@gmail.com", gender.FEMALE, UUID.randomUUID())
//          
                );
    }
```

}

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el error completo que te arroja el programa? Para ver más información sobre el mismo (línea de error y stack). Siempre es útil tener esa información.

Comment: Por lo que se ve haces un llamado a `getAllStudents()` el cual devuelve una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), sin embargo no estás capturando correctamente el posible error de rechazo de dicha Promesa. Sólo tienes un llamado al método `then()`. Te hace falta una llamada al método `catch()`. Es la forma correcta de trabajar con Promesas. Además sabrás la razón del error al poder analizar el objeto devuelto en ese `catch`. Saludos